# Can I re-purchase an app with a different apple ID?

Tags: mac-appstore, apple-id, code-signing

I have a development machine that another employee (who has left) purchased Xcode on. Now I want to update Xcode, but I don't have that employee's apple ID information. I signed out of the App Store and back in with my account, but it won't let me update or re-buy the app because it was originally bought with his account. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply delete the app from your machine. The store prevents two copies of the same app from being installed as a general case

You should then be able to re-buy it as it would be a fresh download - signed for the account you prefer rather than a re-download of the app signed for the old Apple ID.